# Is it possible to make the center of my view equal to (0,0)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am attempting to develop an application that makes use of some simple trig functions. Unfortunately, with the way the coordinate system is set up on the iPhone, amongst many other devices, I am having trouble with my calculations -- all centering around the offset.

*For instance, the app I am creating has a small point that orbits around my center.  Unforunately, because the center is not (0,0), I'm forced to put in any additional check to flip my coordinates (+180 degrees) upon reaching the center as well as adding in additional calculations to the trig functions to adjust -- simply to account for how the origin system works.*

I would *like*  the center of the device, in this case `(160,240)` to be the center origin of my application. e.g. `(160,240)` = `(0,0)`  That would mean, if I were to place any sub view to the *left* of the main view's center, the X coordinates of that view would have a negative X.  Otherwise, I'll have to go through more calculations to adjust for the offset -- which has proven to be a headache thus far.

I've set the origin of my view, using the editor, to the center.  However, anything I drop on the view still retains a top, left *0,0* coordinate structure.

Is this possible?  I would assume sense I can set the origin of my view to center, it must do something useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sublayerTransform` property of your view's `layer`.

```
myView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(160.0, 240.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: So question on that -- If I were to use the sublayerTransform, would any image views already on the main view readjust to new coordinates while retaining their position?  So essentially, If I had an image at 0,0, would it then become (-160,-240)?

Comment: UIView also has its own transform property so you don't have to dig into the layer.

Comment: @George Yes, any subviews would adjust their positions after setting the `sublayerTransform`.

Comment: @Dancreek It's not the same. `transform` transforms the layer/view itself, while `sublayerTransform` transforms its sublayers/views.

Comment: To clarify: If you had an image at (0,0) and then adjust the sublayerTransform, the coordinates would still be (0,0), but it would appear at (160,240).

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Check out UIScreen "Bounds" property:

[Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html)

Should be relatively simple to use these to calculate a transformation for center screen.

Something like:

```
myView.center = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315169/how-to-get-an-x-and-a-y-for-a-cgrect-to-initialize-a-control-with-a-frame)