# How to rotate UIButtons in Circular Direction in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to rotate the three buttons in circular direction so that the Selected button will come to the center and other respective button will get swap accordingly.

Means to be more specific--> If I click on "button 2" it will come to center ie. at current position of "button 3", and "button 3" will be swap to "button 1" likewise.

And after that If i again click on that button(Button 2) it should go to the next page(Next ViewContoller).

Can anyone help me out to achieve this.

If possible please provide any sample code or link for a sample application.

Comment: Do you expect someone to just write this for you or maybe you just forgot to share your code?

Comment: I have created a sample application with fixed UIButtons, but I didnt work on Animation, so give me some guideline to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have your 3 buttons declared as ivars, then you need to do something like this:

```
- (void)rotateLeft {
    CGRect frame1 = button1.frame;
    CGRect frame2 = button2.frame;
    CGRect frame3 = button3.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [button1 setFrame:frame3];
        [button2 setFrame:frame1];
        [button3 setFrame:frame2];
    }];
}

- (void)rotateRight {
    CGRect frame1 = button1.frame;
    CGRect frame2 = button2.frame;
    CGRect frame3 = button3.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [button1 setFrame:frame2];
        [button2 setFrame:frame3];
        [button3 setFrame:frame1];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton* clicked = (UIButton*)sender;
    if (clicked.frame.origin.x == 20) {
        [self rotateLeft];
    } else if (clicked.frame.origin.x == 228) {
        [self rotateRight];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[NextController alloc] init] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This uses the *frame* property to detect which way to rotate. But you should get the general idea from this.

Comment: Thanks, This helps me to create the basic normal frame moving sequence, now I am working on creating better look. Your guidelines in this regard are most appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You need to look into **UIView Animations**.

Basically you need to animate the *center* property of each button when one of them is pressed. Very simple stuff.

There are tons of tutorials on the web if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks for reply,can you please provide the link of tutorials.

Comment: This question may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315169/how-to-get-an-x-and-a-y-for-a-cgrect-to-initialize-a-control-with-a-frame